# Cannot get current location

Tags: java, android, location

I need to get current device location (lat/lng) but "getCurrentLocation()" shows "No provider" all the time so location is null. I call this method in onCreate() and declared all permissions in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Location services on real device are enabled as well.

getCurrentLocation() java code:

```
    public void getCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(c, false);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(location!=null)
    {
        double lng=location.getLongitude();
        double lat=location.getLatitude();
        Toast.makeText(this, Double.toString(lat) + "\n" + Double.toString(lng), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No provider", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

P.S.: I revised a lot of similar questions but can't find suitable solution.

Comment: You have commented the part about permission, did you at least gave the permission using the settings ? (Android 5.0 and prior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all consider using FusedLocationProvider instead of LocationManager. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) you can find guide to how to use id.

Second - you are trying to get "last known location" and it wouldn't always be there. To receive users location you need to subscribe to LocationManager updates. [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) is example how to do it.

Comment: *To receive users location you need to subscribe to LocationManager updates* that's not true. Only if you want updates

Comment: @TimCastelijns if you didn't receive location as a last known then subscribing is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

```
 provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(c, true);
```

try this change in your code

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that `.getLastKnownLocation()` returns a previously stored location data.

It can return a `null`.

So you have to be prepared for the case where you need to listen for location updates. You register to them like this:

```
    locationManager
            .requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, 
                    new LocationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                            //here you receive the new location
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                        }
                    }););
```